# Send a diff to teamcity instead of list of files

Tags: teamcity, pre-commit-hook

Hi is it possible to send a diff patch to a teamcity server using command line tool instead of list of files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do it using the command line tool for  Remote run functionality. You can read the documentation and steps at this [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Command+Line+Remote+Run+Tool) .

However, according to the documentation it sends a list of files that changed rather than a patch.

Comment: That is my question, in docu I see that I can send a list of files but I need to send really a diff content.

Comment: basically I saw the source code of a plugin it looks like it is not possible. I also checked out the "patch" file created by TC it looks to be different than a normal diff -> it has some binary data inside.